# Translate from Python 2.xx to 3.6

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Can someone please help translate the following code from 2.xx to 3.6? I believe the issues I'm having stem from the fact that the urllib2 library changed.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values = """
  {
    "carrierCode": "fedex",
    "serviceCode": null,
    "packageCode": null,
    "fromPostalCode": "78703",
    "toState": "DC",
    "toCountry": "US",
    "toPostalCode": "20500",
    "toCity": "Washington",
    "weight": {
      "value": 3,
      "units": "ounces"
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "units": "inches",
      "length": 7,
      "width": 5,
      "height": 6
    },
    "confirmation": "delivery",
    "residential": false
  }
"""

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': '< Enter your Basic Authorization string here >'
}
request = Request('https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments/getrates', 
data=values, headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

I have made the suggested edits to the code by @t.m.adam and am now getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/map/PycharmProjects/Reverb/SSAPI.py", line 37, in 
    response_body = urlopen(request).read()
  File "C:\Users\map\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\map\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 524, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Users\map\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1248, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`Request` and `urlopen` are part of `urllib.request` in python 3.
You can still use your script if you change your imports :

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
```

Also print is a function in python 3. So use it like that :

```
print(response_body)
```

Comment: Hey @t.m.adam I have made these edits but am now getting an error. I have edited my previous post to reflect this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, POST data should be bytes. You can resolve this issue if you encode `values` , eg : `values = values.encode("utf-8")`